# max-height for vertical writing mode - doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Below is a table with some vertical text. It works OK in Chrome and Edge, but not in Firefox. (I don't have Safari, so I cannot say anything about it.) How to fix it?

```css
.vertical {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

th, td {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
    <th class="vertical">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Chrome and Edge:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  .vertical {
      writing-mode: vertical-rl;
      display : block;
   }
```

just add "display: block"

Comment: Thanks, it seems this works. Do you have a link to this bug in the bug tracker?

Comment: yw:) no, i don't have

Answer (score 1):

its a bug you need to set the height and set word-break to maintain the height if it got more words :

```
.vertical {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    height: 100px;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a link to this bug in the bug tracker? Your solution works, but I'm not sure that using fixed height is a good idea...